# the JS code stop working while ajax load

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

- The code 1: When I click on the "click here" it's supposed to hide the `div` with "id=adiv", and when I click again its show it again.
- The code 2 and 3: the ajax code (code 2) belongs to code 3. but there not belong to code 1! this codes just refresh php page every 1 second.

Why after the ajax code (code 2&3) loads in the page, the 'code 1' stops working? When I click on "click here", its doing nothing.

But before the ajax load, the code 1 works good.

the codes 2 and 3 works good, i have no problem with them. the only problem is with code 1.

**edit:** when i debug this page its show me for the line: "hideshow(document.getElementById('adiv'))" (in code 1), this eror: "Uncaught ReferenceError: hideshow is not defined (anonymous function)".

but i dont really understand why i have this problem? and what i need to do to solve this?

1) The script:

```
<a href="javascript:hideshow(document.getElementById('adiv'))">Click here</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function hideshow(which){
if (!document.getElementById) { return; }
if (which.style.display=="block") { which.style.display="none"; }
else { which.style.display="block"; }
}
</script>

<div id="adiv" style="font:24px bold; display: block">Now you see me</div>
```

2) The ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function refresh(name, url, info, info_1, info_2, type)
{
    if (type == "send") {
        document.getElementById("send_"+name).innerHTML = info;  // just show the txt that send
        Input(name);
        if (info == "") {
            document.getElementById(name).innerHTML="";
            return;
        } 
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {  // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var params = "c=<?php echo $_GET["c"]; ?>&info="+info+"&info_1="+info_1+"&info_2="+info_2;
    xhr.open("POST",url,true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if( this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById(name).innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    xhr.send(params);
    return false;
}
</script>
```

3) The code that play the ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           setInterval("refresh('aaa', 'refresh.php', '', '', '', 'refresh')", "1000");
           </script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure where you would encounter `if (!document.getElementById)` being `true`, at least in fairly recent browsers

Comment: Have you considered using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)'s [`.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method for this?

Comment: Not sure we are seeing all the code here.. is your ajax call replacing the "Click here" link with one that doesn't have the javascript?

Comment: @KeithLantz no, i said that the ajax code not belong to the ajax code 1! i didnt use ajax on code 1

Comment: Did you try debugging it in the browser? Maybe there's an error in code 2 or 3 that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @Hope4You the code 2 and 3 works good. i have no problem with them. the only problem is with code 1

Comment: Run the page with all 3 scripts included (that's what you want, right?) then debug that page and look for errors

Comment: @Hope4You ok. but i dont realy know how to debug. how did i do it?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but do ***not*** pass strings to `setInterval`; it uses `eval`!  Pass a function.  `setInterval(function(){ refresh('aaa', 'refresh.php', '', '', '', 'refresh'); }, 1000)`

Comment: @Hope4You i have chrome or IE 10

Comment: For Chrome: Right-click the page and select "Inspect Element". Then go to the console tab. Check for any errors there, and use your website and see if any errors appear.

Comment: @Hope4You its show me for the line: "hideshow(document.getElementById('adiv'))" (in code 1), this eror: "Uncaught ReferenceError: hideshow is not defined (anonymous function)". but i dont really understand why i have this problem? and what i need to do to solve this?